# How to ignore the keys of dynamic response of json object in retrofit 2.0

Tags: android, json, retrofit2, gson

How to ignore the keys of json which are missing for response of two different users using retrofit 2.0 and gson.

This is the json response for existing user.

```
{ 
   "details" :{
       "userId" : "548sdry5687rtyde346asf",
        "email: "avc@zxc.com",
        "name":{
          "first":"Jhon",
          "last": "Madan",
          "_id":"69874154sdfadg58dfa245"},
          "gender":"male",
          "location":{
              "address":"12547",
              "city":"delhi",
              "state":"Delhi"
          }
     }
}
```

This is the response for new user

```
{
    "details":{
        "userId":"1258afafg287fae23sf",
        "email": "qwea@gmail.com",
        "name":{
              "first":"Mohan",
              "last":"mehar",
              "_id":"kdg2467edfdfh356thdg"}
         }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by ignore? If the keys aren't there usually the json libraries won't crash. The fields will just be null...

Comment: Hi Fred, ignoring the fields in the sense, check out in new user response, there we don't have "location" object. For setting the view of the user profile, we need to access the strings from their respective pojo classes. In this case when i'm trying to register a new user, where it consists only name and email, it is raising a null pointer exception at location, since location object is not there for new user.

Comment: Well, but that's not a problem with retrofit or gson. You have to account in your code for the fact that it can be null and not display it

Comment: How it can be made null or not to display it .. please help me to solve it

Comment: Agree with @Fred. Either create a new `User` class without those fields or perform `if-not-null` checks before accessing those fields.

Comment: Use GsonConverterFactory in Retrofit. And When u define any model, just declare the required keys. Ignore the keys that you dont want. GsonConverterFactory  will automatically give you the response.

Answer (score 3):

If you want your object **not to have the field** but to not care if the json does:

```
class A {
    String first;
    //String gender; //good news, Gson doesn't care by default!
}
```

If you want your object **to have the field** but not to deserialize it even if the json does:

```
class B {
    String first;
    transient String gender; //won't serialize or deserialize
}
```

If you want your object **to have the field** but not care if the json does not:

```
class C {
    String first;
    @Nullable String gender;  //but this is default anyway
}
```

If it's **displaying data** you are worrying about:

```
public String getGender() {
    //has a default value ("") so no NPE's
    return gender == null? "" : gender;
}
```

Comment: Hi @Nick Cardoso, thanks for the answer. But the solution which you had given in Class B with transient annotation, i had tried it earlier, but its not working for me. Please help me to solve the problem with fine solution.

Comment: "solve the problem with fine solution" what does this mean? I have tried to cover all the cases because your question wording is a little unclear - is your problem with converting `Json -> Java` or with `Java -> Json`. Do you have an error?

Comment: For every user i had settled a similar format for view, where i'm setting the strings to the text-views in the view. So if the user is new, he has only name and email. But while setting the view the text-views are asking for the gender or location which are not yet added to the new user, but those keys exists for existing user json response. In this case it is raising a NPE where the text-view is asking for the string which is not there in the json response.

Comment: Then the last part (return default string) is the part you need

Answer (score -1):

GSON will set class fields to null if the corresponding JSON fields are missing. If you want to be able to access these fields without worrying about null pointer exceptions, you can lazily replace the nulls with empty objects upon access.

```java
public String getGender() {
    if (gender != null) return gender;
    else return gender = "";
}

public Location getLocation () {
    if (location != null) return location;
    else return location = new Location("", "", "");
}
```

Answer (score -1):

JSONObject class has a method named "has":

http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#has(java.lang.String)

Returns true if this object has a mapping for name. The mapping may be NULL.

Example

```
if(jsonObject.has("email"))
{
  returen true
}
else
{
  return false  
}
```